# How to design domain with entity referencing entity on another sql server with NHibernate persistance

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, ddd-repositories, cross-database

I need to design domain that has two simple entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; protected set; }
    ...
}

public class Country
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    ...
}
```

It's all nice and clear in domain world but the problem is that User and Country persisted in two different databases on two different servers (tho they are both MSSQL 2005 servers).

**So, how should I correctly implement persistance of entites across different sql servers in NHibernate?**

Using IDs instead of objects in references? Yeah, thats simple but it's hitting hard on the whole domain thing making domain object more like DTO. And it will require that IUserRepository get it's hands on ICountryRepository to load User entity.

Linked servers? Hm... Somehow I don't like it (distributed transactions and no XML columns). And what I should be aware in case of using them and more importantly how should I configure NHibernate to work effectively with linked servers?

Maybe some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard of people using the `schema` property in a class mapping to contain the linked server name (like `otherserver.dbo`), but I don't know anyone that hasn't ran into one problem or another when doing that.

There are a few DDD bootstrapping frameworks that allow you to transparently map entities to different databases (resulting in multiple `ISessionFactories`, which it will manage for you). [NCommon](https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon) is one I would recommend. This assumes, however, that `Country` only exists in one database, and `User` only exists in another.

As for transactions... well, if you use a `TransactionScope` and configure DTS, that might work. NCommon uses a `UnitOfWork` API that also wraps `TransactionScope`.

You would have to change `User` so that `Country` is just an ID. Here's why. You'd end up with two session factories, one that has a mapping for `Country` and the other that has a mapping for `User`. If you don't make that change, NHibernate will complain that there is no mapping for `Country` when you save `User` (since they are stored in two different DBs).

Now you could instruct NHibernate to ignore `Country` property, and keep `Country` so your domain doesn't change. However, when you load `User` from the database next time, Country will be null.

Comment: Um... Just to clarify: NCommon will allow me to map entities transperently and I won't have to change my domain model or no, it can not work like that and I will have to change country entity to countryId value object?

Comment: With NCommon, you will still need to change Country to CountryID and just store the identifier. I'll explain why in an updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I see. But how that change will help me using NCommon? If I understood correctly I will still need to load Country entity manually from different repository - I could do that without NCommon.

Comment: NHibernate supports only one connection string per `ISessionFactory`. You have two databases, you have two `ISessionFactory`. You don't _need_ NCommon, but it does all the heavy lifting of figuring out which `ISessionFactory` to use to get an `ISession` for an entity.

Comment: I've looked into NCommon and it's seems development stopped almost a year ago - the latest commit was 11 month ago and there are some very big issues in github (like TransactionManager and UnitOfWorkManager are not thread safe). Do you have experience using NCommon on production websites?

Comment: Admittedly, it's been a while since I've used it because I've written my own framework. Another one that supports multidatabase mappings that is probably more active is SharpArchitecture. However, in regards to thread-safety of his unit of work and transaction manager: They are designed to be supported by a per-request IoC container, so I think peoples' complaints  are rooted in a misunderstanding of how he's intended it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NHibernate.Shards from NHContrib.

Comment: Arent this is for partioning primary? Can it be used to completely unreleated entity like Country? And does code of NHibernate.Shards completed already so it can be used in production?

Comment: As far as I know, it support putting entities in different dbs and it can be used in production

Comment: I see that this project has alpha release type :|